# Retrieve URLs from XML file and gather data from the URLs to my database - PHP/cURL/XML

Tags: php, xml, curl

The XML contains around 50,000 different URLS that I am trying to gather data from to then insert or updade my database.

Currently I am using this, which sort of works but times out because of the large amounts of data being processed, how can I improve the performance of this:

**URLs.xml (up to 50,000 loc's)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>http://url.com/122122-rob-jones?</loc>
        <lastmod>2014-05-05T07:12:41+08:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.9</priority>
    </url>
    </urlset>
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php
include 'config.php';
include 'custom.class.php';
require_once('SimpleLargeXMLParser.class.php');
$custom = new custom();

$xml = dirname(__FILE__)."/URLs.xml";

// create a new object
$parser = new SimpleLargeXMLParser();
// load the XML
$parser->loadXML($xml);

$parser->registerNamespace("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"); 
$array = $parser->parseXML("//urlset:url/urlset:loc"); 

for ($i=0, $n=count($array); $i<$n; $i++){

            $FirstURL=$array[$i];

            $URL = substr($FirstURL, 0, strpos($FirstURL,'?')) . "/";
            $custom->infoc($URL);
    }
```

**custom.class.php (included bits)**

```
    <?php
        public function load($url, $postData='')
        {

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
                if($postData != '') {
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
                    }
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $result;




        }

        public function infoc($url) {


        $get_tag = $this->load($url);   


        // Player ID

          $playeridTAG = '/<input type="text" id="player-(.+?)" name="playerid" value="(.+?)" \/>/';
        preg_match($playeridTAG, $get_tag, $playerID);      

        // End Player ID

        // Full Name
            preg_match("/(.+?)-(.+?)\//",$url, $title);
        $fullName = ucwords(preg_replace ("/-/", " ", $title[2]));  
        // End Full Name

        // Total    
        $totalTAG = '/<li>
                    <span>(.+?)<\/span><span class="none"><\/span>              <label>Total<\/label>
                <\/li>/';
        preg_match($totalTAG, $get_tag, $total);        
        // End Total        


        $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM playerblank WHERE playerID = '.$playerID[1].'');
        if($query->num_rows > 0) {

        $db->query('UPDATE playerblank SET name = "'.$fullName.'", total = "'.$total[1].'" WHERE playerID = '.$playerID[1].'') or die(mysqli_error($db));

echo "UPDATED ".$playerID[1]."";

        }
        else {

        $db->query('INSERT INTO playerblank SET playerID = '.$playerID[1].', name = "'.$fullName.'", total = "'.$total[1].'"') or die(mysqli_error($db));

echo "Inserted ".$playerID[1]."";

        }




        }

?>
```

**Gathering each URL (loc) from the XML file is no problem, it's when trying to gather data using cURL for each URL that I am struggling to do without having to wait a very long time.**

Comment: Have you tried [`curl_multi_init()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how i'd use that when using a loop (for). However, I will look in to it further.

Comment: So you want to pull in XML from 50.000 URLs without having to wait a very long time? Please define "a very long time".

Comment: If a single request takes 250 milliseconds, 50.000 of them will take 3,5 hours.

Comment: curl_multi_init() is a good option, or you can use a non-blocking language like NodeJS, i made something very similar with nodejs using the request module and its really cool, and fast.

Answer (score 2):

Try using curl_multi. In the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) there's a goot example

```php
// create both cURL resources
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://lxr.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);

$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}

//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch2);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try work with offline copy of XML file, and delete already updating or inserting urls, then start script again untill offline file have urls. Then get new copy of XML file if need.

Comment: Getting the URLs from the XML is working fine, it's the gathering data from each URL that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in "load" function: it blocks execution until single url is ready, while you can easily load several urls at the same time. [Here is explanation](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/) of idea how to do it. The best way to improve performance is to load several (10-20) urls parallel and add new one for loading "on fly", when one of previous done. [ParallelCurl](https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl) will do the trick, something like:

```
require_once('parallelcurl.php');

// $max_requests = 10 or more, try to pick best value manually
$parallel_curl = new ParallelCurl($max_requests, $curl_options);

// $array - 50000 urls
$in_urls = array_splice($array, 0, $max_requests);
foreach ($in_urls as $url) {
    $parallel_curl->startRequest($url, 'on_request_done');
}

function on_request_done($content, $url, $ch, $search) {
    // here you can parse $content and save data to DB

    // and add next url for loading
    $next_url = array_shift($array);
    if($next_url) {
        $parallel_curl->startRequest($url, 'on_request_done');
    }
}

// This should be called when you need to wait for the requests to finish.
$parallel_curl->finishAllRequests();
```